# how can I separate the data where I used split and the one I want to see the whole data using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, split

So what my output does is that when I select a tools name it automatically picks the specification on it and shows the control number, the only problem is when I create multiple data to specify my tools name it only shows the first specified tools name in that data and in my console.log it shows an array.

Here is the picture of my form

[image]

Here is my console.log(response) output

```
PSA-10000@BLACK & DECKER@T-1001@PSA-10000@BLACK & GOLD@T-1001@PSA-10000@BLACK & WHITE@T-1001@
```

Here is my console.log(shouldSplit) output

```
(10) ["PSA-10000", "BLACK & DECKER", "T-1001", "PSA-10000", "BLACK & GOLD", "T-1001", "PSA-10000", "BLACK & WHITE", "T-1001", ""]
0: "PSA-10000"
1: "BLACK & DECKER"
2: "T-1001"
3: "PSA-10000"
4: "BLACK & GOLD"
5: "T-1001"
6: "PSA-10000"
7: "BLACK & WHITE"
8: "T-1001"
9: ""
length: 10
```

Here is the result of what I am getting from ajax to form

```
PSA-10000
BLACK & DECKER
T-1001(Just my unique ID nevermind this)
```

Here is my javascript code

```
    <script>
    //Ajax for control number
    function ToolsChange(element) {
    let tools_id = $(element).val();

    if (tools_id) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "form_JSON_approach.php",
            data: {
                "tools_id": tools_id
            },
            success: function(response) {

                var dataSplit = response;
                console.log(response);
                var shouldSplit = dataSplit.split("@");
                var shouldNotSplit = dataSplit.split();
                console.log(shouldSplit);
                console.log(shouldSplit[0]);
                console.log(shouldSplit[1]);
                console.log(shouldSplit[2]);
                $("#sel_control_num").val(shouldSplit[0]);
                $("#sel_tools_spec").val(shouldSplit[1]);
                $("#sel_tools_id").val(shouldSplit[2]);

            }
        });
    }
  }
```

And here is my ajax code

```
<?php 

include("../include/connect.php");


if(isset($_POST['tools_id'])){
    
    $ID = $_POST['tools_id'];
    $query = "SELECT tools_masterlist.control_no, tools_masterlist.tools_id, 
    tools_masterlist.tools_name, 
    tools_spec.model_num,tools_spec.model_num_val, tools_spec.status
    FROM tools_masterlist LEFT JOIN tools_spec ON tools_masterlist.tools_id = 
    tools_spec.tools_id
    LEFT JOIN tools_registration ON tools_masterlist.control_no = 
    tools_registration.reg_input WHERE 
    status = 1 AND tools_name = '$ID'";

    
    // $result=mysqli_query($con, "CALL GetAjaxForToolsRegistration('$ID')");
    $con->next_result();
    $result=mysqli_query($con, $query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            // $explodeData = $row['control_no'] . " " . $row['model_num'] . 
               " " . $row['tools_id'];
            // $pieces = explode(" ", $explodeData);
            // echo $explodeData[0];           
            echo $row['control_no'] . "@" . $row['model_num'] . "@" . 
            $row['tools_id'] ."@";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // $maxQuery = "SELECT MAX(tools_id) FROM tools_registration";  
    }

}
```

?>

Comment: what is the expected behaviour you are looking for ? `it only shows the first specified tools name in that data and in my console.log it shows an array.` this is unclear

Comment: Hey, for example in my image tools name is air blower and tools specification is black & decker but it has two other specifications in my console.log which is black & gold and black & white. The thing is when I click the button it only shows black & decker, I want to show other data of that data's tools specification, the only thing is I don't know how.

Comment: which line number `console log` output is that ? you have **5**  `console.log` . Post output of  `console.log(response);` . Also better to post it in text rather then a image

Comment: Done editting. What I want to display is number 1,4,7 in console.log

Comment: Great, how do you want to `concat` those strings to display ?  Seperate it using `space` like `BLACK & DECKER BLACK & WHITE BLACK & WHITE` or `comma`  like `BLACK & DECKER, BLACK & WHITE, BLACK & WHITE` ?

Comment: @tinker I should use comma to separate it :) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add a loop in you `success` function to `concat/join`  all array values.

So, the function would look something like below.

```js
success: function(response) {
    var dataSplit = response;
    console.log(response);
    var shouldSplit = dataSplit.split("@");
    var shouldNotSplit = dataSplit.split();
    console.log(shouldSplit);
    console.log(shouldSplit[0]);
    console.log(shouldSplit[1]);
    console.log(shouldSplit[2]);
    $("#sel_control_num").val(shouldSplit[0]);
    
    var specs = [];
    for (i=1; i<shouldSplit.length; i+=3){
        specs.push(shouldSplit[i])
    }
    
    $("#sel_tools_spec").val(specs.join(', '));
    
    $("#sel_tools_id").val(shouldSplit[2]);
}
```

Comment: I am still analyzing what happened to your code, what is specs.push(shouldSplit[i]), it pushes the value of array inside and then displays it? Anyway it worked!, Thanks man :D saved my life

Comment: Refer this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Comment: Thanks! I have another question if it is possible to put the data inside <select> element. ID is not working and append is not working too

Comment: It might be possible using `<select multiple>`. Post another question with full html code and link it here.

Comment: [stackoverflow.com/questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65894461/how-can-i-link-data-to-a-select-element-in-ajax-method) Here is the link :)